# Why "housing" is incorrect in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have been asked to identify which word is incorrect. There are 4 choices- a,b,c, and d. The correct answer is "housing", but I don't know why. Could you please explain to me why "housing" is incorrect in this sentence.

> Troops **housing** in Fort Bliss, Texas, **train** to **operate** aircraft **equipment** and artillery.

Comment: First of all, what are your thoughts on that? Why do you think *housing* as used in your sentence is correct/incorrect?

Comment: I think "housing" could be " who house" , an sobordinate clause .

Comment: Without more context, I'd say it should be 'housed'... but troops aren't housed, they're billeted.

Answer (score 4):

Why is "housing" incorrect in this sentence?

Because the verb "to house" has an active meaning "to put into a house", or "to give shelter to".

However the troops were not actively housing someone else.  Rather, they were on the receiving end of the housing. Therefore a passive construction should be used such as "are housed". In this particular case the options are: "being housed" or just "housed".

Consider the difference between "they are fed" which is passive, and "they feed (the cats, etc)." which is active.

BTW - "stationed" might be a better word choice.

Comment: I'm not really sure this fully gets the 'correct answer' across; though the reasoning looks sound enough to me [I'm no grammarian]. However, "Troops are housed in Fort Bliss, Texas, train to..." doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin , edited

Comment: Cool. ahh, 'stationed'... yeah. I'm UKEng so my first thought was 'billeted' for military personnel, but 'stationed' would work too.